# How to respond to an XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine, xmlhttprequest

I'm using a Javascript to ask our app (which is in Google App Engine) if the file a user wants to upload is already in his list of files (he will overwrite).

I know how to send the request, but how can I create a response from the server, using Python?

This is the request:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

  req.open('POST', 'https://safeshareapp.appspot.com/upload', async);

  req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  req.setRequestHeader("Content-length", body.length);
  req.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

  if (async) {
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
        var response = null;
        try {
         response = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
        } catch (e) {
         response = req.responseText;
        }
        callback(response);
      }
    }
  }

  // Make the actual request
  req.send(body);
```

As you see, we are getting the responseText from the request after everything has gone OK, but my question is **how do we fill that responseText field on the server side??**

Comment: What language are you using, server-side? Say, you're using PHP. Then, you can use: `<?php ...........; echo json_encode($variable_to_serialize); ?>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class MyRequestHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        import json
        result = {"filename": xxx} // just an example, result can be any Python object
        json_obj = json.dumps(result)
        self.response.out.write(str(json_obj))
```

Comment: @c4sh If it solved your issue, click at the Accept answer (at left side of the answer). If it's also really helpful, also *upvote* the answer.